# Python Script to pass input in loop to URL one by one

Tags: python, loops, python-requests

The python output will be like below with `Tags_Value` comma separated and I need to pass the value to another URL one by one.
URL has to be execute with the value in loop. I am new to python, unable to create loop.

input to passed to the URL

```
['ates test', 'TC-MSLBSecond', 'B8.L2s6_McIP.PER', 'BRamp', 'BRlation00001', 'BR.on0.0002', 'BR00003', 'BRtion00004', 'BR00005', 'Bation00006']
```

I want to pass above value to URL one by one in the `Tags_Value`.

```
Input_URL =['https://servername:843/htorian-rest-api/v1/tags/properties/{Tags_Value}'.format(Tags_Value=Tags_Value)]
```

for Tags in Tags_Value:

Input_URL =['https://:8443/historian-rest-api/v1/tags/properties/{Tags}'.format(Tags=Tags)]

def return_json(url):

```
    Tags_Props = requests.get(url)
    json_obj = Tags_Props.json()
    return json.dumps(json_obj)

for url in Input_URL:
print return_json(url)
```

Comment: SO is not here to solve your assignments. Please provide some code you wrote to solve this and explain a specific problem you might have in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to loop over the tags list and add those to the url (not the url as a list). You can use an f-string to insert the current tag:

```
import requests, json

def return_json(url):
    Tags_Props = requests.get(url)
    json_obj = Tags_Props.json()
    return json.dumps(json_obj)

tags = ['ates test', 'TC-MSLBSecond', 'B8.L2s6_McIP.PER', 'BRamp', 'BRlation00001', 'BR.on0.0002', 'BR00003', 'BRtion00004', 'BR00005', 'Bation00006']['ates test', 'TC-MSLBSecond', 'B8.L2s6_McIP.PER', 'BRamp', 'BRlation00001', 'BR.on0.0002', 'BR00003', 'BRtion00004', 'BR00005', 'Bation00006']

for tag in tags:
    print(return_json(f'https://servername:843/htorian-rest-api/v1/tags/properties/{tag}'))
```

Comment: how to pass headers to the print statement?

Comment: Do you mean that you altered my code above and are now getting an error whilst trying to add headers?

Comment: print(return_json(f'https://brhhtc-m.na.com/hirian-rest-api/v1/tags/propert/{Tags_Value}'), headers=headers)
how to add headers, which has the access token to be passed

Comment: I had not altered your code but the headers needs to be passed with the URL as password, so i tried adding the headers but its throwing syntax error. how to add it?

Comment: You need to use a dictionary in the request `headers = {'token':'token_value'} `